# How do I import the namespace of my ViewModel in a Xamarin project ? (Cannot resolve symbol XAMLUI)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I am trying to do the official Xamarin tutorial as seen here: The Code Here(https://youtu.be/VqZeTAjsgFQ?t=412)

When I copy that exact code that is shown in the youtube video I get an error which is as follows

[Screenshot Of My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR5xc.jpg)

This is my first time learning xamarin and I would appreciate all the help.

Comment: please DO NOT post code or errors as images.

Comment: please read the 2nd hint given to you by the IDE

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this [Declaring Namespaces for Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces#declaring-namespaces-for-types) to understand that.

And from the code of shared screenshot:

> xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLUI.ViewModels"

It means the name of project should be `XAMLUI` and there is a folder called `ViewModels` inside it.

For example, the structure of project is as follows:

[image]

Then **Xaml** could use it:

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, so what should I do if I want to use the namespace ie my MainPage.Xaml.Cs code in the MainPage.Xaml file ? that is what theyre doing here arent they?

Comment: @ArunasvaBhuyan The name of your project is `AppXam`, if you also create a folder inside it. You only can use this in your project: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppXam.ViewModels"`. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.